# How to fix the size of MDI Subwindow in Qt

Tags: c++, qt

I'm creating a Desktop Application in Qt and I'm showing subwindow inside the MDI Area. I have the problem that in the size of subwindow adjusts every time I open my code in the other monitor.

My goal is to fix the size of subwindow and make it parent size. Hope you understand my problem.

I'm using this code to change the size and showing the subwindow in mdi area

```
  Subwindow1 = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
  QQuickWidget* widget2 = new QQuickWidget(Map);
  widget2->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
  widget2->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/subwindow1.qml"));
  widget2->show();
  Subwindow1->setWidget(widget2);
  Subwindow1->resize(700,640);
  Subwindow1->setWindowTitle("Subwindow 1");
  Subwindow1->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,false);
  Subwindow1->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  Subwindow1->addSubWindow(Subwindow1);
  mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(Subwindow1);
  Subwindow1->show();


  Subwindow2 = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
  QQuickWidget* widget3 = new QQuickWidget(Camera1);
  widget3->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
  widget3->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/subwindow2.qml"));
  widget3->show();
  Subwindow2->setWidget(widget3);
  Subwindow2->resize(304,270);
  Subwindow2->setWindowTitle("Subwindow 2");
  Subwindow2->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,false);
  Subwindow2->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  mdiArea->addSubWindow(Subwindow2);
  mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(Subwindow2);
  Subwindow2->show();


  Subwindow3 = new QMdiSubWindow(mdiArea);
  QQuickWidget* widget4 = new QQuickWidget(Camera2);
  widget4->setResizeMode(QQuickWidget::SizeRootObjectToView);
  widget4->setSource(QUrl("qrc:/subwindow3.qml"));
  widget4->show();
  Subwindow3->setWidget(widget4);
  Subwindow3->resize(304,270);
  Subwindow3->setWindowTitle("Subwindow 3");
  Subwindow3->setAttribute(Qt::WA_DeleteOnClose,false);
  Subwindow3->setWindowFlag(Qt::FramelessWindowHint);
  mdiArea->addSubWindow(Subwindow3);
  mdiArea->setActiveSubWindow(Subwindow3);
  Subwindow3->show();
```

Answer (score 0):

For example : 
You have Subwindow1 with (700,640)
The code is : `Subwindow1->setFixedSize(new QSize(700,640))`
Hope it help !

https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qwidget.html#setFixedSize